# Why this question was not reopened and closed even after required editing?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

[How do I explain better to my colleagues that they should wish me a happy birthday on a different date?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/14105/how-do-i-explain-better-to-my-colleagues-that-they-should-wish-me-a-happy-birthd?noredirect=1#comment57957_14105)

This question by me was originally not specific. I edited it accordingly but it wasn't reopened. Now it's closed. I really need an answer there. Could somebody tell what should I do now? Do I need further editing for it is still not specific? Or should I ask it on other stackexchange (if yes I would like to know which one)?

Comment: There are already 4 reopen votes at this moment. Just need one more. Sometimes, it takes longer...

Comment: But it's closed now. It can be reopened even after it is closed?

Comment: Thank you. But I really needed an answer there. So it may take may be months (?) to reopen it. That would be really bad :(

Comment: There's little difference between being on hold and closed. As long as it's not deleted (or locked), it can be reopened. And even deleted posts can be undeleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question right now is asking:

> What do I do? How can I answer these questions to them and explain them I really respect my birthday and want to be wished in October?

I think people are leaving it closed because **'What can/should I do' and 'What do I say' are both off topic here,** as per the help-center:

> While this site allows questions that meet the Good Subjective requirements, some questions are too subjective for us. This includes questions that:
>
> lack a clear goal we can address. We can provide solutions to achieve goals but we can not tell you what your goal should be. Questions should state the preferred outcome of the situation clearly.

---

> Other types of questions that are off topic include questions that:
>
> ask us to rewrite text or otherwise tell you what to say. We are not an editing service. Questions should focus on how to generally write or decide what to say so that you can tailor them to your situation.

---

On top of that, there's still pending requests for clarification in the comments:

> ... Also "I feel they will troll me" I do not understand that sentence in this context, could you explain? [link](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/14105/how-do-i-explain-better-to-my-colleagues-that-they-should-wish-me-a-happy-birthd?noredirect=1#comment57482_14105)

What does that mean?

So, right now, this question is not in a shape where it is fit for IPS and can be reopened. Please think a little more about what skill you're struggling with and want to improve (that would be your goal), focus on your own behaviour and not on what you're wanting your colleagues to do.